# Xfinity Modem can ping NIC; computer cannot ping modem

Tags: drivers, server, 16.04, realtek

I've been all over the boards and am having trouble getting my NIC to interact with my modem. I've chatted with Comcast, but I think this was beyond the scope of the tech.

My newly built (by me, not my first) Ubuntu Server 16.04.01 is unable to access the Internet.

My Xfinity modem can ping the nic of my server. If I restart my modem the server's mac address appears in the modem interface as a connected device.

If I ping the modem (gateway) from the server it causes the server to become an Offline Device in the modem interface.

If I leave it alone (I'm not sure how long) it becomes an Online Device again.

Finally, I get to the question. Is this a driver issue, or modem issue?

According to `lspci` the NIC I'm using is a Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411.

If I run `ifconfig` it shows `up broadcast running multicast MTU:1500`

I suspect the driver for the NIC has to be installed. I think I've got the correct driver, `0004-rtl_bsd_drv_v191.tgz`, and have copied it to a folder I created in my profile. I've also extracted it. At this point I'm stumped.

It contains:

```
if_re.c   if_ereg.h    Makefile   README.txt
```

The README file is blank.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If your ethernet is using the r8169 driver, you should replace it with `r8168-dkms` using Synaptic. The r8169 driver is buggy.

Start Synaptic, click the RELOAD icon, then the SEARCH icon, type `r8168-dkms`, mark it for install, click the APPLY icon. Quit Synaptic. Reboot.

If you only have a command line to deal with, type `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install dkms`, then `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms`. Then reboot.

Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS.

Let me know how you do.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Apt-get doesn't work - no access to internet. As it happens, the driver I'm trying to install is the 8168. I've listed the contents I've extracted from the .TAR file, but now am at a loss for what to do with them. - Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 0004-rtl_bsd_drv_v191.tgz driver that you have looks like nothing that I recognize. Can you either plug in a USB wireless network dongle, and connect to the Internet that way, or download the `r8168-dkms` and `dkms` installers on another machine, and then move it over using a USB flash key? Cheers, Al

Comment: `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.2_all.deb` and `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb`. Cheers, Al

Comment: `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic/PackageDownloadScript`. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi Al, Still working on it. I installed Debian desktop version and was able to get the nic to work, but I had to make sure that it used IPv4 only and then update the driver as you suggested. I may set aside Ubuntu Server for a different distribution; perhaps Red Hat.

Comment: Thanks for the update. With the file download locations that I gave you, stick them on a USB flash drive, and give Ubuntu Server another chance. Cheers, Al

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Comment: No luck; I'm trying a USB Ethernet adapter but am having trouble with that as well. I made a point of getting on that has linux drivers available, but it's not mounting, I think. It's a Startech USB 3 Gigabyte NIC.

It's so odd, because my modem "sees" the mac address and IP addressing assigned to the built in NIC, but I can't ping it from the modem and I can't ping the modem from the server. Argh!

Comment: Did you remember to configure /etc/network/interfaces?